# Account is disabled immediately after creating it?

Tags: facebook

I had a Facebook account several years ago but deleted it.  A few weeks back, I tried to create a new account with my new email address.  Soon as I did that, the system must have thought I was doing something wrong because it disabled me.
I found this section on the help area:
https://www.facebook.com/help/103873106370583

There is a form you can fill out, submit your ID and then wait for a response.  It's been over 2 weeks and I still have not received a response yet.  Is there any other options for contacting Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form is the only way to reach out to Facebook. I have not seen any other way to contact Facebook.

You are not getting response because sometimes they take around months to reply. And sometimes they do not restore account at all if they notice policy violation.

From the [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/103873106370583) (Help Center) you have given in question:

> Keep in mind that in some cases we may not issue a warning before disabling your account. We can't restore accounts that were disabled for severe violations of the [Facebook Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/).

Best way to keep appealing to restore your account and make sure to not violate Facebook Community Standard in Future.